# What is the most appropriate method to model time series of fantasy football points?

Tags: regression, time-series

I have a dataset of football (soccer) data, where for each player in a given season, I have the (fantasy football) points scored in a particular match, the opposition attacking and defensive strength for that match, and a number of other variables. For example:

[image]

I want to predict the points scored by a particular player in their next match - marked by the question mark in the picture above. We know the opposition strength already for the next match - each team has a strength calculated at the start of a season and it doesn't change. Therefore we don't need to forecast these values and can factor it into our prediction of the points that will be scored.

My initial idea was to do a simple regression (linear) for now, by taking a moving average of the past N matches (orange shade in pic below) and the opposition strength for the upcoming game (yellow) to predict the points that will be scored:

[image]

Such that for a given match we have the following dependent and independent variables:

[image]

The next sample would be taken by moving the window by 1 sample, and using the next match as the target:

[image]

This would also allow me to measure the correlation between the moving average of points and the target points - a measure of the "form" of a player i.e. how well their most recent performances predict their next performance controlling for the opposition difficulties.

However, I've been having doubts mainly around whether this approach satisfies the conditions for regression: Would the samples resulting from the sliding windows be truly independent?

Beyond that, I've also been wondering if a timeseries model would be more appropriate. From my initial reading it looks like timeseries models are traditionally univariate and it might be difficult to control for opposition strength in my prediction. It also seems like it would be difficult to measure "form" directly with a timeseries model as I propose for the regression. Perhaps a hybrid approach where I use a timeseries model to forecast the points for the next match and then input this to a regression with the opposition strength variables?

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.